Java socket TCP
I have to make a project of a multiplayer words game using TCP / sockets and swing GUI. I made the server class with threads (to handle multiple clients) and implemented runnable and I made the client class and the interfaces of the game.
The problem is, how do I connect the server and client classes to the GUIs? like the players array how do I make their names appear on the screen? The user must enter their name in a GUI then presses a button then a waiting room would show up with all the connected players' names, I did the GUIs but coding these functionalities is hard. I tried to add the username with String username = jTextField1.getText(); it worked when i moved to the next panel, but when i tried to add the username to the array in the server class it caused an error.
Also, how do I make the points counter in the GUI increments once a player answers? and how do I implement the chat between the players inside the GUI?
The project would've been a bit easier without the GUI I'm having trouble I hope someone could help me with it!!
The codes contain some unused things since ive been trying things
I did the server + client + GUI designs but connecting the server and client with the GUI is the problem
these are ethe codes:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket; import java.net.ServerSocket; import java.util.ArrayList;
public class NewServer {
private static final int MaxPlayers = 3 ;
private static final int WinScore = 5 ;
private static ArrayList<NewClient> clients = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Waiting for client connection");
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to client");
        
        // Create a new instance of Menu for each client
        Menu menuFrame = new Menu();
        menuFrame.setVisible(true);
        
        NewClient clientThread = new NewClient(client, clients); // new thread
        clients.add(clientThread);
        
        new Thread(clientThread).start();

    }
}
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException; import java.io.InputStreamReader; import java.io.PrintWriter; import java.net.Socket;
public class ServerConnection implements Runnable {

private Socket server;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;

public ServerConnection(Socket s) throws IOException {

    server = s;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
}

u/Override
public void run() {

    String serverResponse ;
    try {
        while (true) {
            serverResponse = in.readLine();
            if (serverResponse == null)
                break;
            System.out.println("Server says: " + serverResponse);
            
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            in.close();
            out.close(); // Closing PrintWriter
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException; import java.io.InputStreamReader; import java.io.PrintWriter; import java.net.Socket;
public class Client { private final static String server_IP = "localhost"; private static final int server_port = 9090;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try (Socket socket = new Socket(server_IP, server_port)) {
        
        ServerConnection servcon = new ServerConnection(socket);
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        new Thread(servcon).start() ;

        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("> ");
                String command = keyboard.readLine();
                if (command.equals("quit")) {
                    break;
                }
                out.println(command);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket; import java.util.ArrayList;
public class NewClient implements Runnable {
private Socket client;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;
private ArrayList<NewClient> clients;
public String username;

public NewClient(Socket c, ArrayList <NewClient> clients) throws IOException {

    this.client = c;
    this.clients = clients;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
}

u/Override
public void run() {

    try {
        while (true) {
                
            String request = in.readLine();
            outToAll(username + ": " + request);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IO Exception in new client class");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void outToAll(String substring) {

    for (NewClient aclient:clients) {
        aclient.out.println(substring);
    }
}
}


First, Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  This means, you shouldn't be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread or trying to update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. I would suggest making use of a SwingWorker at some point.  Personally, I would create some kind of "event" model, which can "publish" events (ie stuff coming from the sever) and "post" events (ie send stuff to the server).

When new content arrives from the server, you bundle it up in some kind of "event" wrapper and add it to the event queue (probably a blocking queue), you could then use a SwingWorker (for example) to read from this queue and "publish" the events onto the Event Dispatching Thread, from where you then notify interested parties via some kind of observer. You might consider looking into some kind of "event bus" implementation if you don't want to roll your own

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
